# ¿Cómo habilitar un div en React?

Tags: html, reactjs

Mi pregunta va a que necesita deshabilitar un div en React, pero la propiedad disabled no funciona para ello.

Alguna conoce que otra propiedad se podría de usar? O si existe otra forma de deshabilitar el div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

En tu componente asigna la propiedad `disabled` al elemento `div`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'StackOverflow',
      disabled: false,
    };
  }

  handleState = () => {
    this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div disabled={this.state.disabled}>
          <button>DISABLED: {this.state.disabled.toString()}</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleState}>Enable/disable</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

y agregas el siguiente estilo al elemento div:

**** Esto hace la magia *****

```
div[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Aca te dejo el enlace como evidencia y el codigo

https://react-playground-practice-n3uqaw.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-practice-n3uqaw?file=index.js